# Evaluation order of duplicated kernel parameters

Tags: linux-kernel

If the kernel command line contains multiple settings for the same parameter, how are they evaluated?

Example:

```
nohz=off ... nohz=on
```

Which setting 'wins'? The last one?

And is the evaluation logic the same for each parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be the last one.

The parameters are handled by `init/main.c`, which uses `parse_args()` from `kernel/params.c`, which scans them serially. For each one it invokes `parse_one()` which ends up calling a callback depending on the parameter.

Since a callback is involved, all parameters can affect your system, regardless of their order.

For `nohz`, the parameter is registered and handled by `kernel/time/time-sched.c`:

```
__setup("nohz=", setup_tick_nohz);

static int __init setup_tick_nohz(char *str)
{
    return (kstrtobool(str, &tick_nohz_enabled) == 0);
}
```

So it sets and unsets the flag. If there's nothing else in between then it should have no effect.

The kernel developers are reasonable people and they wouldn't add parameters whose behavior depends on the order they are passed, so I'd assume that in most cases the distance of the two won't play a role.

... but ...

`parse_args()` also has a check:

```
    if (irq_was_disabled && !irqs_disabled())
        pr_warn("%s: option '%s' enabled irq's!\n",
            doing, param);
```

which indicates that the callback of a flag may do non-trivial stuff like enable irqs.

This logic/scanning also checks for module parameters (i.e. kernel parameters in the form of modulename.flag=xxx) and I wouldn't blindly trust what the modules choose to do.